# "'firebase' is not defined" error when using firebase.firestore.timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm using firebase, authentication and storage without problems in my React app. However, when I tried to use the firebase timestamp, I'm getting "'firebase' is not defined" error.

How I use timestamp:

```
    const duedate = moment().add(1, 'd').toDate();
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(duedate)
```

I have firebase etc. initialized in a different file. I tried all possible imports:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app;
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app;
import firebase from 'admin/compat/app;
```

and many variations. Nothing seems to help.

I'm using the latest version of firebase. Do you have any idea on how to solve it please?

Edit: This is how I import Firebase in the firebase.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {

};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you didn't import firebase in the file where you want to use Timestamp, and only in the file where you initialize?

Comment: Yes, exactly... I don't really know how to do it. I do import "db", and all other functionalities work (getDoc, setDoc, etc). It's only the timestamp that is giving me the error.

Comment: You have to import in every file where the symbol is being used. That's how JS and most other programming languages work. One import will not provide the variable for the entire project.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have edited the question to show you how I import Firebase. Could you please advise me on how to import it to the file where I want to use the timestamp? So far I have imported "db" only, but it keeps giving error. Thank you!

Comment: Do it in the same way as you do the file where you are initializing successfully.

Comment: I'm sorry @DougStevenson, I'm obviously very new at this... Does it mean I need to include all the imports including config data in each file? Because even when I import all possible functions from my initialization file (import { db, app, storage, auth } from "lib/firebase";), it still throws the error. I'm also confused why all other functionalities work, but not the timestamp. Am I maybe refering it in a wrong way? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to do the import in any file where you intend to use it.  If you have other problems after that, you should post a different question describing the new problem.

Comment: It is still the same problem. The question is precisely how to import so that it doesn't give me this error. I tried everything - I even copied the whole config data into the file where I'm using timestamp. It still tells me firebase is not defined. Could you please explain it to me like I'm five? How do I import firebase into the file so that timestamp works. There must be something I'm missing. None of the answers in similar threads were helpful for me. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer after many trials and errors, maybe it helps another lost beginner.

The problem was that I needed to import all the below, and not just firebase, apart from the configuration that I've already been importing from my config file.
When importing only the first line below, it was still showing me the error 'firebase is not defined'.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```